# using a fetched api data in all screens

Tags: json, api, flutter

I'm new on flutter.
Trying to code a city guide application.
I m getting all needed data from web api with one request at startup.

I want to do fetching 1 time and show different parts of data in different screens.
But i cant reach data in all views. As an example, my response is below, i want to send "news" to news.dart, news dart is another screen from the main page.
What kind of architecture should i use?
Maybe creating a singleton class for all data and request it in different views?

My response is something like that;

```
{
"version" : "1.0",
"news" : [
  {
    "title" : "title of content 1",
    "content" : "content 1"
  },
  {
    "title" : "title of content 2",
    "content" : "content 2"
  },
],
"cafes" : [
   {
    "name" : "cafe 1 name",
    "image" : "cafe1img.jpg"
   },
   {
    "name" : "cafe 2 name",
    "image" : "cafe2img.jpg"
   }
]}
```

Comment: I think it's better to learn about State Managment in flutter , like Provider

Comment: You should probably start by reading the flutter documentation about state management: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro